# Python retrieve value from a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
[
        {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "string 1"
        },
        {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "string 2"
        },
        {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "string 3"
        },
        {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "string 4"
        }
]
```

Is there any way to can retrieve the `"id"` of the first dictionary `{"id": 4, "name": "string 4"}` based on its `"name"` `"string 1"` ?

Comment: Sure, just iterate and when you have a match on one value, you have the other. Or create a dictionary from the list (mapping name values to id values) and you can do it efficiently for multiple names. Were you stuck with your attempts somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

This should work, it iterates through the list of dictionaries to find the dictionary that has a name that is equal to your target and prints out its id

```
for dictionary in list:
    if dictionary["name"] == target:
        print (dictionary["id"])
```

Comment: did you try this? you probably mean `i["name"]`

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension can do the trick:

```
a=[
        {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "string 1"
        },
        {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "string 2"
        },
        {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "string 3"
        },
        {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "string 4"
        }
]
result = [ x for x in a if x["name"] == "string 1" ]
```

You can use `result = [ x["id"] for x in a if x["name"] == "string 1" ]` if you just want a list of the ids which match the search string.

Answer (score 0):

One line code for your problem.

```
output = [ value["id"] for value in a if value["name"] == "string 1" ]
```

This will return list of all id's in a which have name equal to string 1.